# Not able to transfer AES encrypted file through socket programming

Tags: java, sockets, aes

I'm trying to transfer an AES encrypted file through socket programming, but when I specify the file path it gives the following exception, and when I try to transfer an unencrypted file, it works fine.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: salt.ecn (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at nigam.Front.server(Front.java:52)
    at nigam.Front$7.run(Front.java:621)
```

Code:

```
public class SocketFileExample {
    static void server() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(3434);
        Socket socket = ss.accept();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("salt.ecn");
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        copy(in, out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    static void client() throws IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 3434);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\SIDDHARTH\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Nigam\\salt.ecn");
        copy(in, out);
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    server();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

        client();
    }
}
```

'Code:    Encryption code used'

```
      Code:    Encryption code used
          public class AESFileEncryption {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    // file to be encrypted
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream("plainfile.txt");

    // encrypted file
    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("encryptedfile.des");

    // password to encrypt the file
    String password = "javapapers";

    // password, iv and salt should be transferred to the other end
    // in a secure manner

    // salt is used for encoding
    // writing it to a file
    // salt should be transferred to the recipient securely
    // for decryption
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);
    FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("salt.enc");
    saltOutFile.write(salt);
    saltOutFile.close();

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory
            .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 65536,
            256);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    //
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

    // iv adds randomness to the text and just makes the mechanism more
    // secure
    // used while initializing the cipher
    // file to store the iv
    FileOutputStream ivOutFile = new FileOutputStream("iv.enc");
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    ivOutFile.write(iv);
    ivOutFile.close();

    //file encryption
    byte[] input = new byte[64];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
        byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
        if (output != null)
            outFile.write(output);
    }

    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
    if (output != null)
        outFile.write(output);

    inFile.close();
    outFile.flush();
    outFile.close();

    System.out.println("File Encrypted.");

}
```

}

Comment: must be the wrong path or a different one... Try printing out the absolute path you get when choosing with a JFileChooser.

Comment: Its working when i give the path using JFileChooser but I want to give path using the above mentioned way. And its showing exception only for encrypted file.

Comment: make sure the path is completely correct... salt.ecn? maybe salt.enc? [as i see in your code...]

Comment: i already checked it. I think its something because of encryption .

Comment: Are you positive because of the above code you have shown me it seems you have a typo: "FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("salt.enc");"
   yet you do: "OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\SIDDHARTH\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Nigam\\salt.ecn");"    is it not supposed to be "salt.enc" not "salt.ecn"? It is certainly not because of encryption, look at the error... the file doesn't exist in the path given.

Comment: Your path is messed up. You misspell your `salt.enc` file or maybe its suppose to be `salt.ecn`. Check all the places where you have that as a parameter